# Generate a SoftLayer_Security_Ssh_Key object API

Tags: ssh, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I want to generate a new SSH Key for my SoftLayer account.

I found an example of how to upload a generated key.
https://developer.ibm.com/marketplace/docs/technical-scenarios/obtain-virtual-server-ibm-cloud/

But what I want is to generate a key, so I tried to call the following REST but I'm not able to make it work

Http Method: [POST]

API: rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Security_Ssh_Key.json

Body:

```
{   "parameters": [
     {
       "label": "new-ssh-key"
     }
]}
```

Respose:

```
{
"error": "Key is required."
"code": "SoftLayer_Exception_Public"
}
```

Also, I checked the methods of SoftLayer_Security_Ssh_Key but it doesn't have any method to generate a key.

Do you know if it is even possible to generate a SSH Key by calling the SoftLayer API ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to generate a Ssh Key through API. The API just creates a record, that will attach a ssh key to your account (So, in this case you need the Ssh Key already generated)

The API will do the same like this:
https://control.softlayer.com/devices/sshkeys

Comment: Thank you for your reply, any plans to add that kind of API? I see other IaaS Providers having it.

Comment: You can submit a ticket with this requirement or send an email to: **PortalFeedback@softlayer.com**, to be considered for its implementation